# How to make responsive legend text for canvas chart

Tags: canvasjs

I am working on canvas chart and I am facing issue in responsiveness of legend text for mobile device.

Could you please let me know how can I set legend text responsive for mobile device?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Please help me out to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no way you can make contents of <canvas> responsive unless you calculate everything on your own. Go mobile first :https://www.uxpin.com/studio/blog/a-hands-on-guide-to-mobile-first-design/

Comment: Do you mean clipping of axis-label? If so, you can try combination of labelAngle & labelMaxWidth. Also can you share the code, so that anyone can look into the options you are using and guide you properly?